# Android NDK and Static Library

Tags: android, android-ndk

My app crashes when I call a nativ func.
When I build my native code the output is:

StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a

SharedLibrary  : libnsipjni.so

Install        : libnsipjni.so => libs/armabi/libnsipjni.so

Why doen't it install the static library? How shold the Android.mk reflact the static library? Should I load it in my JAVA code?

Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your static library first and then add

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARY := stdc++

In the Android.mk for the sip lib. This will include the static library in your shared lib.

Comment: It build the static library atomaticaly, can u pls specify a bit more on the Android.mk

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify what you got so far? Are you using a method table?

Example on android.mk if the static library isnt defined, first create a module containing the static library, if stdc++ is used you can skip to next part of the make file:

```
#ARM7
#Include POCO JSON LIBRARIES: libPocoJSON.a using the headers in ../JSON/include
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE := PocoJSONArm7
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Poco/arm7/libPocoJSON.a 
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES :=/Users/exjobb/poco-1.5.1-all/JSON/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := -DFOO=1 -fpermissive -O3
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Next import this module:

```
# make file for compiling your c++ code to shared library here....

# Add the static libraries
#LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES :=PocoJSONArm7 <- Your library is in stdc++
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARY := stdc++ # <- This is where you load your library

LOCAL_LDLIBS     := -llog
LOCAL_CFLAGS     := -O3 -DPOCO_ANDROID -DPOCO_NO_FPENVIRONMENT -DPOCO_NO_WSTRING -DPOCO_NO_SHAREDMEMORY
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS   := -frtti -fexceptions -O3

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```